# Label.FontColor = Executescalar not working

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a label turn different colors depending on if there is data in the cell it pulls from a database.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        SqlConnection sqlCon6 = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DataCleanup;Data Source=dev_sql_vm");
        SqlCommand sqlCmd6 = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd6.CommandText = "SELECT AccStatus FROM PDMStatus where Series = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        sqlCmd6.Connection = sqlCon6;


        sqlCon6.Open();
        object result6 = sqlCmd6.ExecuteScalar();



        if (result6 != null)
        {
            label8.Text.System.Drawing.Color.Green = sqlCmd6.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        else
        {
            label8.Text.System.Drawing.Color.Red = sqlCmd6.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        sqlCon6.Close();
```

The error I get is

'string' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please help and thanks!

Comment: This code makes no sense.  Try `label8.BackColor = Color.Green;`.  Don't keep calling ExecuteScalar, just use your result6 variable.  And give your variable names better meanings.

Comment: Um... you're trying to assign a new color to "green"?

Comment: As previously mentioned, your variable naming needs to be more clear if you expect to be able to maintain this code. Also allowing user controls to build your where clause (line 3) is generally a bad practice and typically vulnerable to SQL Injection. Research Parameterized queries and stored procs to improve this vulnerability. And lastly, your Data Layer code should not be interacting with your user interface directly. If you want a query to use info from a text box, use arguments passed through your method. The top comment from LarsTech should address the actual issue you reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
label8.Text.System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

`Label.Text` property is a `string` storing what it displays.
If you intend to change the color of it, you have to change the `Label.ForeColor` property.

---

```
if (result6 != null)
{
    label8.Text = result6.ToString();
    label8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
else
{
    label8.Text = "AccStatus not found.";
    label8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. Seems to be the correct answer to me.